# jQuery remove tr with no results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I have a SQL-PHP printed table, and a select at the top of the table. The table contains contacts classified by towns.

At the beginning, the table shows all contacts. If I specify the town, I want to hide the rest.

I'm trying to use a jQuery script

```
    <script>
    function updateit(){
    if ($("#table").filter("tr") === $("#selectTown").val()) $(this).show(););
    else {$(this).hide();};
    }        
    </script>

    [...]
    <select id="selectTown" onchange="updateit()"><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="TX">Texas</option></select>
    <table id="table">
    bla bla bla...
    </table>
```

Before I tried with `find()` function, but with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: debugging hint: execute your selectors in javascript console. E.g. in developer tools in chrome, firebug console in firefox etc.

Comment: Could you not use `$('#table tr')`?

Comment: What you tried isn't even valid syntax. And how can we suggest for you a way to filter the rows when you've replaced them with `bla bla bla...`?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to compare to `$("#selectTown").val()` if i'm not mistaking, that will compare either an HTML DOM element or an jQuery object to either a string which will never be valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `$("#table").filter("tr") === $("#selectTown").val()` compares document elements to string, it would not work.

Simplest solution would be to do all elements hidden and than select and show all matching elements. Example:

```
$('tr').hide();
$('tr[value=' + $("#selectTown").val() + ']').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got the idea for this code, but `filter()` definitely doesn't do what you think it's doing.  `$("#table").filter("tr")` is going to give you a list of `tr` elements in the table.  That list itself isn't going to equal any selected value, it's just an array of elements.

Mocking up a few things in [a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JSBsj/), perhaps you want something more like this:

```
$('#selectTown').change(function () {
    $('#table tr').hide();
    $('#table tr').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('td:first').text() === $('#selectTown').val();
    }).show();
});
```

What this does is:

1. Bind to the `change` event of the `select` element (which is preferred over the inline binding you do in your markup, just in general).
2. Hide all of the `tr` elements first, you'll show the ones you want in a moment.
3. Show all of the `tr` elements which match the filter.

The filter in this case is a function which returns `true` if the text inside of the `td` element (you will likely need to update that selector) equals the selected value.  The main difference here vs. what you tried is that `.filter()` is returning a list of matched (filtered) elements, not an actual value to compare.  Internal to the filter is where the comparison takes place, in this case using a function (which needs to return true or false for any given element being filtered).